# Is it necessary to use MVVM pattern or architecture components in android for beginners in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have already built 80% of my app without following a MVVM pattern or using android architecture components such as View Model, Livedata etc because most of the tutorials didn't follow these patterns. My code just has data models and business logic, data binding on the activity, fragments itself.

Just got confused about the fact that whether is it okay to launch an app in the old school style or I should rework with some architecture pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Its ok to use any pattern you think is best for your app.  There are no requirements, technical or policy wise, about how you implement your code.  If you feel MVVM is right use it.  If you don't, avoid it. Even Google wouldn't claim its the best for every usecase, its just another tool in the box.

Comment: thank you so much for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Architecture components solve a bunch of complex problems.  Among these are:

- Code maintainability
- App performance
- Consistent behavior across devices and versions of Android

That last one is key in my opinion. Rolling your own architecture can lead to bugs as your app gets exposed to more and more devices after release. Devices that you just didn't see during testing.

I would not hold up your app's launch to integrate architecture components, but certainly you should consider refactoring your app where it makes sense as you update it for future releases.

Comment: He's not talking about rolling his own, but about a completely different type of architecture that doesn't use it.  I'd also disagree about not rolling your own-  many of Google's architecture components have assumptions that may not work for your apps, or are just mediocre solutions.  Use them when they make sense, use alternatives (including rolling your own) where that makes sense.  Just because Google wrote it doesn't mean its right.

Comment: I didn't say just because Google wrote it it's right.  The question was specifically about android architecture components or another MVVM vs not using one at all (what I called rolling your own) and I was offering my opinion.  Speaking from experience, I have better luck using a widely adopted pattern than rolling my own.  If existing patterns/architectures/libraries don't fit, of course roll your own.  And of course, consider everything that is out there.

Comment: No, not using one single pattern is not "rolling your own"-  "rolling your own" means rewriting a component.  Not not using it at all.  And there's dozens of commonly used patterns in Android-  MVC, MVP, MVVM, and others.  His question was about using one particular one.  You may have misunderstood his question, but you definitely didn't answer it.